# How to use FeatureDetector in OpenCV C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I am using VS 2008 with OpenCV 2.1 installed as per the installation guide. FeatureDetector/SurfFeatureDetector are listed as classes in the documentation, but they are considered "syntax error : identifier 'SurfFeatureDetector"

This is pretty much the entirety of my code.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

Ptr<FeatureDetector> *detect = new SurfFeatureDetector();
```

I've tried a bunch of random combinations to get this to work. How can I initialize a featuredetector?

Comment: What kind of pointer is that?

Comment: ack, edited. Should be type FeatureDetector

Comment: Ptr is opencv auto pointer which deletes itself in the end of use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have installation problem, try resinstalling from here: [sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.2)

anther other option is that your precompiler already has `__OPENCV_OLD_CV_H__` defined. 
Try undefining it before `#include "cv.h"`

When you type  `#include "cv.h"`
It automatically should include featurs2d. in fact cv.h includes the following:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/flann.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring a pointer to a cv::Ptr -- you really should just have the cv::Ptr. Change your code to

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detect = new SurfFeatureDetector();
```

and it should work.

Comment: It is still unable to compile, it still doesnt seem to be able to find FeatureDetector. Someone said it's in feature2d.hpp, which I cannot find in my OpenCV2.1 installation, could that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Do you have `using namespace cv;` somewhere in the code? You'll have to include that or declare the `cv` namespace manually. I have used these classes before and never had to include "features2d.hpp," however looking over some of my old code I did also `#include <cxcore.h>` which might be necessary.

Comment: You might want to double check that you are using OpenCV 2.1 for sure, too. Is features2d.hpp present in /usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d? You might also be able to check with `pkg-config opencv --modversion` depending on how you installed openCV.

Answer (score 0):

You need the OpenCV 2.x style C++ include. See below

```
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detect = new SurfFeatureDetector();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>
```

(from here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/411/feature-detector-crash/)